# Converting balanced payments form into Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, balanced-payments

I want to convert this [balanced payment](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/overview.html#collecting-credit-card-information) form into rails-haml. I tried but my submit button doesn't do anything. Probably because I don't know how to pull of a submit outside of a form_for.

This is the form they gave as an example. [Click here to view the whole thing in Jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mjallday/BtXfr/)

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="credit-card-form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Credit Card Details</legend>
        <label>Card Number
            <input type="text"
                   autocomplete="off"
                   placeholder="Card Number"
                   class="cc-number" value="4111111111111111">
        </label>
        <label>Expiration
            <input type="text"
                   autocomplete="off"
                   placeholder="Expiration Month"
                   class="cc-em" value="01">
            <span>/</span>
            <input type="text"
                   autocomplete="off"
                   placeholder="Expiration Year"
                   class="cc-ey" value="2020">
        </label>
        <label>Security Code (CSC)
            <input type="text"
                   autocomplete="off"
                   placeholder="CSC"
                   class="cc-csc" value="123">
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">
            Tokenize
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is what I tried

```
#credit-card-form
  = label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number"
  = text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, :value => "4111111111111111", class: "cc-number"
  %br
  = label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)"
  = text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, :value => "123", class: "cc-csc"
  %br
  = label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration"
  = select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "cc-em"}
  = select_year Date.new(2020), {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "cc-ey"}
  %br
  = submit_tag "Subscribe"
```

Comment: Doesn't this form correspond to any model in your app?

Comment: Nah, the payment API takes the information and never lets it hit my backend so this isnt model backed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this

```
%form#credit-card-form{:action => "#", :method => "POST"}
  = label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number"
  = text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, :value => "4111111111111111", class: "cc-number"
  %p
  = label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)"
  = text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, :value => "123", class: "cc-csc"
  %p
  = label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration"
  = select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, class: "cc-em"}
  = select_year Date.new(2020), {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, class: "cc-ey"}
  %p
  / = submit_tag "Subscribe"
  %button.btn{:type => "submit"}
    tokenize
```

Answer (score 1):

Using html2haml:

```
%form#credit-card-form{:action => "#", :method => "POST"}
  %fieldset
    %legend Credit Card Details
    %label
      Card Number
      %input.cc-number{:autocomplete => "off", :placeholder => "Card Number", :type => "text", :value => "4111111111111111"}/
    %label
      Expiration
      %input.cc-em{:autocomplete => "off", :placeholder => "Expiration Month", :type => "text", :value => "01"}/
      %span /
      %input.cc-ey{:autocomplete => "off", :placeholder => "Expiration Year", :type => "text", :value => "2020"}/
    %label
      Security Code (CSC)
      %input.cc-csc{:autocomplete => "off", :placeholder => "CSC", :type => "text", :value => "123"}/
    %button.btn{:type => "submit"}
      Tokenize
```